# Routing from Aurelia TypeScript-Kit from Getting Started doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia

I've downloaded both **JavaScript** and **TypeScript** kit and followed Aurelia instructions for routing from the [getting started](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.0.3/doc/article/getting-started) page

The JavaScript example works fine but the TypeScript shows the following error on the console when the app is run:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
ERROR [app-router] Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:8080/welcome.js 
ERROR [app-router] Router navigation failed, and no previous location could be restored.
```

Does anyone have experienced the same problem?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I'm assuming "something" isn't compiling the typescript files into javascript, but I haven't worked with typescript before so am not sure what...

Comment: I tried manually compiling the files, the files did compile, but even when the welcome.js file existed the error was the same

Comment: It is looking for it in the wrong place. If I copy the compiled (compiled from typescript) welcome.js and welcome.html files one directory above the src directory then it works.... Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I posted the issue Aurelia's github page https://github.com/aurelia/beginner-kits/issues/12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rob Eisenberg posted an answer to my issue I put up on github.
https://github.com/aurelia/beginner-kits/issues/12

He said to make sure the moduleId of the router looks like this ./welcome.